# CLR in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I am a bit confused about SQL CLR. When i use the below query , then am i using CLR?

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
    new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * from items where name like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Please provide a simple explanation of SQL CLR with some real example

Comment: As a side-note: you should not concatenate a SQL string from user input without checking the value first as the code above is susceptible to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are using ADO.NET from a .NET program (running on the CLR) to query a SQL database.
Except from the `textBox1.Text` part this could have been code running in SQL CLR.

SQL CLR is like stored procedures written in c# or VB.NET. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136.aspx) provides a couple of examples.

Answer (score 0):

The context of SQL CLR refers to using managed .NET code as the language for programmability inside your database. If you where to deploy that code to SQL server as a DLL then I believe you would be "using the CLR" in the context of your question.